# Oozie with Spark Java action

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, oozie

I have tried Oozie with Spark by using Java action.

- Oozie version 4.1.0.3
- Spark Version 1.2.1.

The same code is working fine when I run using spark-submit. But from Oozie, it is giving an exception.

In Java code, I have selection statement `using hiveContext.sal("select * from..")`, at the time of getting a collection.

Note: I have no where found 1s in hive-site.xml

Exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "1s"

Find the `workflow.xml` I used as below

```
<action name="scala_java">
    <java>
    <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
    <job-xml> ${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${appRoot}/mysite/hive-site.xml </job-xml>
    <configuration>
    <property>
    <name>oozie.hive.defaults</name>
    <value>${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${appRoot}/mysite/hive-default.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>pool.name</name>                                                
    <value>${etlPoolName}</value>
    </property>
    <property>                                             
    <name>oozie.use.system.libpath</name>                                             
    <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>                                               
    <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first</name>
    <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>                                               
    <name>oozie.launcher.pool.name</name>                                             
    <value>${oozieLauncherPoolName}</value>
    </property> 
    <property>                                            
    <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>                                            
    <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>                                          
    <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>                              
    </property>
    </configuration>
    <main-class>org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit</main-class>
        <arg>--master</arg>
        <arg>yarn</arg>
        <arg>--num-executors</arg>
        <arg>64</arg>
        <arg>--executor-memory</arg>
        <arg>8G</arg>
        <arg>--driver-memory</arg>
        <arg>2G</arg>
        <arg>--executor-cores</arg>
        <arg>5</arg>
        <arg>--queue</arg>
        <arg>testq</arg>                                       
        <arg>--class</arg>
        <arg>Test</arg>
        <arg>MyScala-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</arg>
        <file>MyScala-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</file>
       </java>
    </action>
```

How to solve this problem?